# HTML in json string causing error

Tags: php, json

i have the following simple json in php script.

```
echo '{"rows":"'.$rows.'", "other_prop":{}}';
```

while `$rows` is:

```
<tr><td>this is gant</td>
        <td>2015-05-21 12:42:11</td>
        <td><pre>[gant id="135"]</pre></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="button load-gant" data-gantname="_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11">Load</a> <a href="" class="button delete-gant red" data-gantname="_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11">Delete</a></td></tr><tr><td>bunda</td>
        <td>2015-05-21 12:47:36</td>
        <td><pre>[gant id="139"]</pre></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="button load-gant" data-gantname="_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36">Load</a> <a href="" class="button delete-gant red" data-gantname="_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36">Delete</a></td></tr>
```

JSON lint keep saying

```
Parse error on line 2:
{    "rows": "<tr><td>this is gan
-------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

what i've did is trying to escape each double quotes, and also escape every tags using `htmlentities()`. but still, lint saying the same words.

whats the problem, and how to fix this?

Comment: Uhm ... `$rows` doesn't contain a json.

Comment: @YUNOWORK : updated. rows is just a property with string as its value

Comment: @DarielPratama my guess is that the problem is your `"` is not escaped in the html and is breaking the JSON string. Can you post the entire JSON that you put through lint? Or see my answer for code that handles this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine with this value of `$rows`

```
<tr><td>thisisgant</td><td>2015-05-2112: 42: 11</td><td><pre>[gant id='135']</pre></td><td><a href='#' class='buttonload-gant' data-gantname='_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-2112: 42: 11'>Load</a> <a href='' class='buttondelete-gantred' data-gantname='_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-2112: 42: 11'>Delete</a></td></tr><tr><td>bunda</td> <td>2015-05-21 12:47:36</td><td><pre>[gant id='139']</pre></td><td><a href='#' class='button load-gant' data-gantname='_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36'>Load</a> <a href='' class='button delete-gant red' data-gantname='_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36'>Delete</a></td></tr>
```

Just kept the value in single line and replaced all `"` to  `'`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `json_encode` and php objects? For example:

```
<?php
$rows =<<<HTML
<tr><td>this is gant</td>
<td>2015-05-21 12:42:11</td>
<td><pre>[gant id="135"]</pre></td>
<td><a href="#" class="button load-gant" data-gantname="_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11">Load</a> <a href="" class="button delete-gant red" data-gantname="_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11">Delete</a></td></tr><tr><td>bunda</td>
<td>2015-05-21 12:47:36</td>
<td><pre>[gant id="139"]</pre></td>
<td><a href="#" class="button load-gant" data-gantname="_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36">Load</a> <a href="" class="button delete-gant red" data-gantname="_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36">Delete</a></td></tr>
HTML;
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->rows = $rows;
echo json_encode($obj);
```

This produces the code:

```
{"rows":"<tr><td>this is gant<\/td>\r        <td>2015-05-21 12:42:11<\/td>\r\t        <td><pre>[gant id=\"135\"]<\/pre><\/td>\r\t\t        <td><a href=\"#\" class=\"button load-gant\" data-gantname=\"_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11\">Load<\/a> <a href=\"\" class=\"button delete-gant red\" data-gantname=\"_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11\">Delete<\/a><\/td><\/tr><tr><td>bunda<\/td>\r\t\t\t        <td>2015-05-21 12:47:36<\/td>\r\t\t\t\t        <td><pre>[gant id=\"139\"]<\/pre><\/td>\r\t\t\t\t\t        <td><a href=\"#\" class=\"button load-gant\" data-gantname=\"_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36\">Load<\/a> <a href=\"\" class=\"button delete-gant red\" data-gantname=\"_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36\">Delete<\/a><\/td><\/tr>"}
```

which is valid according to JSON lint

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your variable like this to use it in JSON which will be string..

```
    $row="<tr><td>this is gant</td>"+
    "<td>2015-05-21 12:42:11</td>"+
    "<td><pre>[gant id='135']</pre></td>"+
    "<td><a href='#' class='button load-gant' data-gantname='_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11'>Load</a><a href='' class='button delete-gant red' data-gantname='_GANT_this_is_gant__2015-05-21 12:42:11'>Delete</a></td></tr><tr><td>bunda</td>"+
    "<td>2015-05-21 12:47:36</td>"+
    "<td><pre>[gant id='139']</pre></td>"+
    "<td><a href='#' class='button load-gant' data-gantname='_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36'>Load</a> <a href='' class='button delete-gant red' data-gantname='_GANT_bunda__2015-05-21 12:47:36'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
```